# the request was aborted Could not a create SSL/TLS secure channel webClient C#

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

Hello Guys i Have a Problem in WebClient the Problem is i can't download
a specific file using WebClient.downloadFile Or WebClient.DownloadFileAsync
the Erorr is [ The Request Was Aborted: Could Not Create a SSL/TLS Secure Channel] and the downloaded files is 0bytes Please Help me with any code
thats download a file or a give a soultion for my Problem 
My Code is :

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.DownloadFile("https://github.com/MohammedZr/roepo/blob/master/x82bit/32bit.exe", @"C:\Users\MohamedAlzurghni\Desktop\Project\bolo\test\32bit.exe");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the error, the connection is not established on TLS.

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.DownloadFile(new Uri("https://github.com/MohammedZr/enchantress/blob/master/x82bit/xmrig.exe"), @"C:\Users\MohamedAlzurghni\Desktop\Project\bolo\test\32bit.exe");
```

You have to set the security protocol used by your servicepoint.

Comment: thanks man for the quick answer i edited my code and now throwing an new error [  the request was aborted the connection was closed unexpectedly ] and the file size is 0 bytes any help ? thanks alot

Comment: i edited my comment thanks for the fast reply i'm really grateful

Comment: the same problem the file size is 0 bytes

Comment: It means no file exists at that path. Would you confirm it?

Comment: what path the download URL ? or what can you be more pacific?

Comment: alright maybe the url i paste the url from repo in github like this i opened the file path and open it [https://github.com/MohammedZr/roepo/blob/master/x82bit/32bit.exe] so this is the url ?

Comment: Click on that URL, it will say page not found.

Comment: ok a new url can i download file from this link !? https://github.com/MohammedZr/enchantress/blob/master/x82bit/xmrig.exe

Comment: the url was wrong i now my bad ! it's possible to download a file from github repo right?

Comment: Yes, you can download. I have tested and updated the answer. Please accept it if it works for you.

Comment: Can you check with:     System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: i checked it 0bytes

Comment: it download's but not the same size its given me a 66kb

Comment: i open it with notepad and it's downloading a html file are sure that downloading from github it could be possible?

Comment: Seems there is some limitation on download size beyond 64KB.

Comment: i fix it the problem is in headers i add this header ```C# Client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla"); ```C#

Answer (score 6):

Set the security protocol to Tls12

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.DownloadFile("https://github.com/MohammedZr/roepo/blob/master/x82bit/32bit.exe", @"C:\Users\MohamedAlzurghni\Desktop\Project\bolo\test\32bit.exe");
```